# Which of the Light Novels does the Anime of Accel World Cover

Tags: accel-world

looking at the [Light Novels List on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accel_World#Light_novels) i assume that Novels 1 and 3 are used but i am wondering if that's it or any of the others are used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Accel World the anime 1st season covers Volume 1-4 + two short histories from Volume 10. (possible spoilers at the end)

> - Volume 1: episodes from 1 through 5
> - Volume 10 1st Short history: episode 6 and 7
> - Volume 2: episodes from 8 through 12
> - Volume 3: episodes from 13 through 17
> - Volume 10 2nd Short history: episode 18 and 19
> - Volume 4: episodes from 20 through 24

Is important to notice that the two OVA's are not part of the main Light Novel series.

Comment: i had a suspicion that it was like this looking at the names but i could only really tell from volumes 1 and 3, using logic i would assume 4 because it seems to fit into the theme of Silver Crow regaining the ability to fly so from there i guessed volume 2 but i wasn't too sure that's why i asked, i haven't seen the anime in a while so i'm guessing 18 and 19 is with that Enemy controlling player who is apart of the Research Group while Kuroyukihime was at the beach but i can't remember 6 and 7

Comment: @Memor-X most people doesn't remember 6-7 because.... huh, what I was doing?